# WiFi connection dropping randomly

Tags: windows-8

My WiFi connection randomly drops with the following message in event log:

> The browser has forced an election on network
>   \Device\NetBT_Tcpip_{F7CCEBC3-DDA9-4502-AF3D-1F016D5D6B07} because a
>   master browser was stopped.

Troubleshooting via tray icon connects the WiFi. This happens 2-3 times a day.

**Update 1**: Disabling WinHTTP Web Proxy service has no effect.
**Hardware**: Atheros AR9002WB-1 NG Wireless Network Adapter

Comment: This is for windows 7 but might be related: http://www.sevenforums.com/network-sharing/233135-winhttp-web-proxy-internet-dropout.html

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett Disabled `WinHTTP Web Proxy` service. Startup was set to mannual but this service was running. Will it cause any any problems?

Comment: Did you try to run `Troubleshoot utility`. If yes then what error you get?

Comment: Troubleshooting fixes the problem temporarily but WiFi drops again after some time.

Comment: what is your wifi hardware?

Comment: @SnippetSpace Added info about hardware.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the drivers provided by your pc vendor try to uninstall those and let windows manage your card. This also works the other way around.

If this doesn't fix it there is another problem.

Seems that there are a lot of driver problems for this card:

- http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/41953-18-atheros-ar9002wb-spontaneously-disconnects
- http://www.eightforums.com/network-sharing/2580-unable-connect-wireless-network.html
- [tons more...](https://www.google.fr/search?q=Atheros%20AR9002WB-1%20NG%20windwos%208&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:en-US:IE-Address&ie=&oe=&redir_esc=&ei=n0WJUJ_-J-eb1AX-hoHgAw#hl=en&safe=off&rls=com.microsoft:en-US:IE-Address&spell=1&q=Atheros%20AR9002WB-1NG%20windows%208&sa=X&ei=n0WJUKmfPOXF0QXwjIG4BA&ved=0CBwQvwUoAA&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=e5ea1dc36937cbd8&bpcl=35466521&biw=1920&bih=985)

You may want to try this driver: http://drivers.softpedia.com/get/NETWORK-CARD/Atheros/Atheros-AR9002WB-1NG-WLAN-Driver-100067-for-Windows-8.shtml although it may in theory not be safe. Atheros (qualcom) does not provide any drivers on its website...

Another potential source of drivers. Try the latest one if the one above does not work: http://www.atheros.cz/atheros-wireless-download.php?chipset=31&system=5

Answer (score 0):

Though I can't see how (and the tech who did it couldn't explain it), a firmware update on my Dell seriously helped this problem. It's worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Spent half the day trying to figure this out on a Toshiba Windows 8 Laptop... WiFi kept dropping every few minutes then would reconnect... after trying every setting I could think of with no luck I stumbled on to a SOLUTION. I went to Control Panel>Device Manager>Network Adapters>Wireless LAN>Properties>Advanced>Bandwidth>the default was set to "20_40MHz" I set it to "20MHz Only". Problem SOLVED!! The WiFi Connection has been working flawlessly ever since.

Comment: That is not the OP's problem, though; the OP is having issues with the master browser election, which is completely unrelated to the bandwidth of your Wifi.